# Initialize SQLite Cursor before accessing data from it

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to insert data into a SQLite DB once a notification is received via FCM. For debugging purpose I am also inserting a dummy data into my DB when SHow Token is clicked on the HomeScreen activity.

However am getting

"I am getting "Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

Link to my code: - [GitHub](https://github.com/jotinder/OneView_Alerts)

Can someone please go through my code and let me know where I am going wrong.

**Note** - I added below in HomeScreen.java,MyFirebaseMessagingService.java and NotificationDetails.java

*private SQLiteDB dbHelper = new SQLiteDB(this);*

since the suggested 
*private SQLiteDB dbHelper;* 

did not work for me

When I used above I kept on getting Nullpointer exception, so I figured since the SQLiteDB class constructor is accepting a context, so let me pass one, post which I did not get NullPointer Exception.

Now I did this without being fully aware of the concept on context which I have been trying to wrap my head around, but since am an extreme noob to android I am not able to grasp it just yet. I suspect it might have something to do with the context I am passing.

Can someone please help me here with detailed instructions on how to fix this issue, I have been through many other threads on this but was not able to fix hence after 5 hrs of going through multiple SO questions, I am posting this one.

Thanks in advance to everyone in the community for the help. :)

### Edit

Upon suggestion by admins, I am including below snippet of my code.

**Where I am calling the cursor**

```
   dbHelper.insertNotification("This is a notification");
                //Check if the message contains data
                Cursor rs = dbHelper.getAllNotifications();
                rs.moveToFirst();
                token_text.setText("Token: " +rs.getString((rs.getColumnIndex("NOTIFICATION_DETAILS"))));
```

**Insert Notification Function in SQLiteDB.java**

```
public boolean insertNotification(String notification){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NOTIFICATION_DETAILS,notification);
    db.insert(NOTIFICATION_TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    return true;
}
```

**getAllNotifications function**

```
public Cursor getAllNotifications() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + NOTIFICATION_TABLE_NAME, null );
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I am getting "Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than posting a comment with the error message. Also be sure to include a **complete** code example. (Note: we are not admins. We are just regular users of Stack Overflow that volunteer time to answer questions.)

Comment: Log out the value of `rs.getCount()` after you `moveToFirst()`. Does your cursor have any rows?

Comment: And are `NOTIFICATION_DETAILS` and `"NOTIFICATION_DETAILS"` equal? (Note the quote marks)

Comment: @MichaelDodd Thank you so much for pointing out the quotation marks !! It did solve my primary issue. You are god sent !!

However now am getting 
_CurosrIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2_

this is in NotificationDetails.java file

Dont want to be asking questions without doing my own homework, so will continue to search for this issue on the forum, however if you can point out the mistake here it would be great ! Thanks a ton !

Comment: `Cursor rs = dbHelper.getAllNotifications();
            rs.moveToFirst();

            do{
                for (int i = 0; i < rs.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    notification_array.add(rs.getString((rs.getColumnIndex(NOTIFICATION_DETAILS))));
                }
            }while (rs.moveToNext());`

Comment: **Index 2 requested, with a size of 2** is indicating that you have read past the end of the cursor. size of 2 = max index of 1.

Comment: not ***getColumnCount()*** use **getCount()**. You want to loop through the number of rows not the number of columns in a row.

Comment: Saying that using `while (rs.moveToNext) { ..... }` is much simpler

Comment: @MikeT Thank you so much.
I ended up using below and it resolved the issue.
    
`while(rs.isAfterLast()){
                notification_array.add(rs.getString((rs.getColumnIndex(NOTIFICATION_DETAILS))));
                rs.moveToNext();
            }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.**

Is saying that you are attempting to get the column at offset -1 from row 0 (the first row). So you have provided an invalid offset ***(it cannot be an offset of -1, the offset must be 0 or greater and the maximum value will be 1 less than the number of columns in the Cursor)***.

The most likely cause, is that Cursor method  **getColumnIndex(the_column_name_as_a_string)** will return **-1** when the column passed to the method cannot be found in the Cursor. Noting that due to a bug column name is case sensitive.

As such your issue is that the Cursor does not contain a column name **NOTIFICATION_DETAILS** and as you have used * (all columns) then that column does not exist in the table.

By the looks of it you should be using the String variable **NOTIFICATION_DETAILS** so  you probably need to use :-

```
token_text.setText("Token: " +rs.getString((rs.getColumnIndex(NOTIFICATION_DETAILS)))); //<<<<<<<<<< double quotation marks removed.
```

### Additional

You should NEVER assume that moveToFirst (or any Cursor move???? method) actually does the move. You should **ALWAYS** check the returned value. It will be **true** if the move was successful otherwise it would be **false**.

- **Again note that the column name passed to the getColumnIndex method is case dependant.**
- As such you should use something like

:-

```
       dbHelper.insertNotification("This is a notification");
       //Check if the message contains data
       Cursor rs = dbHelper.getAllNotifications();
       if (rs.moveToFirst()) {
           token_text.setText("Token: " +rs.getString((rs.getColumnIndex(NOTIFICATION_DETAILS))));
       } else {
           ........ code here if anything need to be done if there are no rows extracted 
       }
```

### Addition re comment :-

> Cursor rs = dbHelper.getAllNotifications(); rs.moveToFirst(); do{ for
>   (int i = 0; i < rs.getColumnCount(); i++) {
>   notification_array.add(rs.getString((rs.getColumnIndex(NOTIFICATION_DETAILS))));
>   } }while (rs.moveToNext());

using the following is much simpler :-

```
Cursor rs = dbHelper.getAllNotifications();
while (rs.moveToNext()) {
    notification_array.add(rs.getString((rs.getColumnIndex(NOTIFICATION_DETAILS))));
}
```